# Can't remove Telegram keyboard using ReplyKeyboardRemove

Tags: node.js, telegram, telegram-bot, node-telegram-bot-api

I'm making bot on Node.js. I have so me problem with removing keyboard.
Here is how my message looks:

```
chat_id: *****,
text: '',
reply_markup: JSON.stringify({
    ReplyKeyboardRemove: {
        remove_keyboard: true
    }
})
```

I'm receiving this message, but keyboard not removing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found what was the problem. 'text' can't be empty and ReplyKeyboardRemove is not needed. Here is working code:

```
chat_id: *****,
text: 'some text',
reply_markup: JSON.stringify({
    remove_keyboard: true
})
```